# size objects in a ListView flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to be able to reduce the size of the view objects, in particular the size of the Qr, and the labels are too stuck together. I have this code which is the only way until now that I have succeeded in which if I open the keyboard it moves me correctly everything up. while I had tried with Column or SingleChildScrollView but there was always something not working well. so I would leave the code like this, except that it must be able to change the size of the objects.

can anyone help me set up?

```
    return FutureBuilder<UserData>(
future: contentManager.getUserData(),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
  if (snapUserData.hasError)
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("There was some error"),
      ),
    );
  if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appColors.yellow)),
      ),
    );
  return Container(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
    color: appColors.primaryColor,
    child: ListView(
      //alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: [
        // TITOLO
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Positioned(
            top: size.height * .05,
            child: Text(
              localization.showQR,
              style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                color: appColors.green,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Positioned(
              top: size.height * .10,
              width: size.width * .8,
              child: qrCodeHolder),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Positioned(
            bottom: size.height * .18,
            width: size.width * .8,
            child: AutoSizeText(
              localization.home_subLabel,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              maxLines: 1,
              style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                color: appColors.green,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          //bottom: size.height * .08,
          //width: size.width * .7,
          //height: size.height * .05,
          child: Positioned(
            child: TextField(
              inputFormatters: [
                new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
              ],
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                //height: 2.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
});
```

[image: mysituation]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of a `Text` widget by changing its `fontSize`.

```
Text(
      'Your text',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
    )
```

For all other widgets, you could try wrapping them in a `Container` with set `height` and `width`.

To space items, you can wrap them in `Padding` or use empty `Container` widgets as spacers between your existing widgets. Here's the doc about [padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html).

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Text('Hello World!'),
  ),
```

To put some Padding around a `Row` here's what you have to do:

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(196.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Text'),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: and for the top or bottom ?

Comment: I have to space the various objects between them, they are all too close together .. I tried with a Positioned but it doesn't work since I'm not using a Stack .. I don't know how to do it. now the code is perfect, everything works, I just have to space the objects between them

Comment: heck thanks to the great, it finally works for me! last thing, with the code above, how do I insert a buttonm at the same height as the textfield, but to the right?

Comment: Put both Textfield and Button inside of a Row

Comment: luckily I solved it, now I would like to ask you something that I haven't been able to do yet. I have to space the row from the ListView, how can I do?

Comment: I tried to use padding but it doesn't make me insert it anywhere in the Row